# ggvis not giving more than 10 distinct colours for fill

Tags: r, ggvis

I am using ggvis to plot clusters point in two dimensions. I have already clustered these points in greater number of dimensions. so every point in addition to its x,y cordinates has a Cluster number (range 0:-20). I want to generate a scatter plot where every point is positioned as per its co-ordinates and its colour should be as per its cluster. I am able to generate a scatter plot using the data. But for fill i am not getting distinct colours for cluster numbers greater then 10. Below is my code:

```
nm_clust%>% ggvis(~x, ~y, key := ~id,fill = ~factor(cluster)) %>% 
layer_points()%>% set_options(width = 1000, height = 1000,resizable=T)%>% 
add_legend("fill", title = "Clusters")%>%
add_tooltip(add_values,"hover")
```

The factors of cluster column of the dataset is as below:

```
levels(factor(nm_clust$cluster))
[1] "0"  "1"  "2"  "3"  "4"  "5"  "6"  "7"  "8"  "9"  "10" "11" "12" "13" "14"
 [16] "15" "16" "17" "18" "19" "20"
```

Can somebody tell where am i going wrong?

Comment: I suppose this is an early development limitation. To bypass that, you may follow the answer from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24810470/custom-fill-color-in-ggvis-and-other-options