# Use layer_text() and layer_points() in one plot at the same time

Tags: r, ggvis

I'm new to ggvis and have a fairly simple question. I want to display data points in a scatterplot as well as their labels. The individual plots are easily produced:

```
# Render as Points ...
mtcars %>% ggvis(~wt, ~mpg) %>% layer_points()
# or as labels of `wt`
mtcars %>% ggvis(~wt, ~mpg, text:=~wt) %>% layer_text()
```

But the combination of both does not work.

```
mtcars %>% ggvis(~wt, ~mpg, text:=~wt) %>% layer_text() %>% layer_points()
```

I get this error:

```
Error: Unknown properties: text.
Did you mean: stroke?
```

The documentation on layers did not help here (http://ggvis.rstudio.com/ggvis-basics.html#multiple-layers, http://ggvis.rstudio.com/layers.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a working solution using [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24701419/heat-map-with-numbers-in-ggvis).

The proper way to do this is as follows:

```
mtcars %>% ggvis(~wt, ~mpg) %>% layer_text(text:=~wt) %>% layer_points()
```