# How to put labels over bars in a bar plot in R in ggvis?

Tags: r, ggvis

Consider a layer_bars() plot in ggvis. How can a user add numbers (labels) above each bar?

Like in graph below:
[image]

Comment: Can you add an example dataset and the initial code you would use to make a bar chart using ggvis?

Comment: Would you be alright with a solution in ggplot2?

Answer (score 1):

You can compute the dataset for the bars and text using `compute_count`.  This is much like the `compute_bin` example in the [ggvis basics docs](http://ggvis.rstudio.com/ggvis-basics.html).

Getting the text aligned takes some work, see[this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24701419/heat-map-with-numbers-in-ggvis) based on [this open github issue](https://github.com/rstudio/ggvis/issues/243).

```
mtcars %>% 
    compute_count(~factor(cyl)) %>%
    ggvis(x = ~x_, y = ~count_) %>%
    layer_bars(fill = ~x_) %>%
    layer_text(text := ~x_, prop("x", ~x_, scale = "xcenter"), y = ~count_ + .5, 
             fontSize := 18, align := "center") %>%
    scale_nominal("x", name = "xcenter", padding = .9, points = TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: @userJT Did this not answer your question?